# NBehave and NUnit-2.5.5.10112 can work together?

Tags: nunit, nbehave

I'm using `Unit-2.5.5.10112`. How can I use also NBehave, if it has dependency on an older version of NUnit?

Should I ignore NBehave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get NBehave 0.4.5 to use NUnit 2.5.5.10112 by doing the following:

First, create an NBehave-Console.exe.config containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework"
                          culture="neutral"
                          publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.5.2.9222" newVersion="2.5.5.10112" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This tells the CLR loader that when NBehave-Console.exe looks for 2.5.2.9222 of nunit.framework, it should use 2.5.5.10112 instead.

Second, put nunit.framework.dll version 2.5.5.10112 in the `C:\Program Files\NBehave\0.4.5.183` directory, replacing the older version.